# getstatusoutput returning 'unsupported operand type(s)'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to substitute the values of strings on `commands.getstatusoutput`, but it gives me the below error:

```
ping_out = commands.getstatusoutput("ssh %s 'ping -c 2 %s'") % (jmp, ip)
```

`jmp` and `ip` are my string variables.

When I call the above command, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
>>>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean `ping_out = commands.getstatusoutput("ssh %s 'ping -c 2 %s'" % (jmp, ip))` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
("ssh %s 'ping -c 2 %s'") % (jmp, ip)
```

The parenthesis are wrong:

```
("ssh %s 'ping -c 2 %s'" % (jmp, ip))
```

The `% (jmp, ip)` belong to the `"ssh %s 'ping -c 2 %s'"` string